# SassError when defining custom themes using Angular Materials

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, themes

I'm trying to create a custom theme for Angular Materials using the guide described here:https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme

However I get an error when defining the color of the light theme: here is the code:

```html
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as `color` or `typography`.
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

The Error I get is this:

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./src/styles.scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: Function mat-light-theme is missing argument $accent.
> on line 17 of src/styles.scss
>
> > $candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
> > ------------------^
> > Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you fix this? Did you at any point downgrade node sass? I think that's what's causing this for me

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```